# How do i make my assistant respond to a preset response to "how are you" in python code after asking them how they are

Tags: python

I am making a voice assistant in pycharm and I have been trying for a while to allow it to respond to "how are you" the assistant is able to respond to other questions like who is _____ and what is the time. I have tested the code and there are no problems and the assistant understands what I tell it but it doesn't respond to the actual question. Any help in rectifying this problem would be great!

```
def Howareyou(text):
    # getting the assistant to respond to 'how are you?'
    Howareyou = ['how are you', 'how are you doing']

    Howareyou_response = [
        'im doing great', 'im fine', 'im a lot better now that you have shown up', 'im doing good']

    # if the user says how are you return a how are you response
    if 'how are you' in text:
        response = response + ' ' + random.choice(Howareyou_response)

    # if the user says nothing return an empty response
    return ''
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I see you're a new contributor, so I advise you to check out [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Can you elaborate on what the expected and actual behavior of your code is? What is `response`? Do you mean to include a `return` statement in the `if` branch?

Comment: Also, as a side note, you may want to take a look at [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for some standard conventions for formatting Python code.

Comment: Hi Bryan, sorry if my question formatting is not the best I just joined and I read both the How to ask a good question and how to create a minimal reproducible example and I reformatted the title. Although I don't know how this isn't a minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

This will work, you just have to make sure you're returning whatever your response is.

```
import random

def Howareyou(text):
    # getting the assistant to respond to 'how are you?'
    Howareyou = ['how are you', 'how are you doing']

    Howareyou_response = ['im doing great', 'im fine', 'im a lot better now that you have shown up',
                          'im doing good']

    # if the user says how are you return a how are you response
    if ('how are you' in text):
        response = random.choice(Howareyou_response)
        return response

    # if the user says nothing return an empty response
    return ''

print(Howareyou("how are you?"))
```

Comment: Jimmy, thank you for sending me the alternative. Whilst the assistant now responds, it responds instantly even though I have not asked how they are.  It does respond to the question with one of the preset responses but I want to be able to ask it first before it responds. I deleted the last line of code you put and whilst it did let me ask the question it didn't respond.

Comment: Is there a way I can directly message you Jimmy so I can send you the whole code and find the error